# Include style one CSS class to another

Tags: html, css, extends, saas

Is that possible to include styles of one css class to another? I mean SASS **@extends** pretty much does a similar thing, but it also styles extended class, which is not required. See example:

```html
<style>
.myclass1{
  background:red;
}

.myclass2{
  color:blue;
  @extend .myclass1;
}
</style>

<div>
  <p class="myclass2">Hello i am class 2, my text is blue and background is red</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="myclass1">Hello i am class 1, my text should not blue and my background is red</p>
</div>
```

Posted example is inspired by article of [CSS-tricks Web](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/), but here everything is very confusing it is not working as it should. **myclass2** should give **myclass1** according to article. However, it is giving strange output. Am I heading in the right direction? or is the article wrong?

**Update:**
Question is only about the actual concept behind **@extend** of SAAS, and including other CSS class to another, and what is the difference?

Comment: Seems to be working fine in the code snippet?

Comment: ...you still have to compile the SASS in order for `@extend` to work.

Comment: From the article you link to: *All three of the most popular CSS preprocessors support extend*. You aren't using any preprocessor, you are trying to treat it as CSS, which it isn't.

Comment: If you don't want to use a preprocessor you can use PostCSS and https://github.com/jonathantneal/postcss-sass-extend otherwise you need to use a preprocessor

Answer (score 4):

**CSS without pre-processors** (SASS, LESS etc.):

```css
.myclass1{
 background:red;
}

.myclass2{
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p class="myclass1 myclass2">Hello, I am of class 2 (my text is blue) and of class 1 (my background is red)</p>
</div>

<div>
<p class="myclass1">Hello, I am only of class 1 (my background is red)</p>
</div>
```

You can add multiple classes to the same element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comma to match multiple selectors:

```css
.myclass1, .myclass2 {
  background: red;
}
.myclass2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p class="myclass2">Hello i am class 2, my text is blue and background is red</p>
<p class="myclass1">Hello i am class 1, my text should not blue and my background is red</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

SASS is a CSS preprocessor which basically means the SASS syntax gets compiled into plain CSS. The features that SASS offers such as `@extend` as well as establishing variables with the `$` syntax etc. are only possible using SASS (not possible with CSS3)

That being said, you would be able to accomplish the result of the `@extend` feature of SASS in regular CSS simply by chaining classes together:

```
.blue, .green {
 <your css here>
}
```